# jquery data selector find all elements with a certain data-value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show all elements which have a certain data- attribute set to a specific value and then hide all other elements with the same data- attribute but with a different value.

The code I have seems to hide all elements whether they have the data- attribute or not.

```
$('*').filter(function() {return $(this).data(dataAttr) == dataVal;}).show();
$('*').filter(function () { return $(this).data(dataAttr) !== dataVal; }).hide();
```

I need this to be dynamic as I am passing in the name of the data- attribute and the value to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The code I have seems to hide all elements whether they have the data- attribute or not.

That's because you are selecting all elements with `'*'`. If the elements don't even have such an attribute, you are comparing `undefined` against the value (`undefined !== someValue`) is probably always `true`.

Select all elements having the attribute first, hide them and then show the ones with a specific value:

```
$('[' + dataAttr + ']').hide()
.filter('[' + dataAttr + '="' + dataVal + '"]').show();
```

I decided to use selectors here because I believe that using `.filter` and `.data` will be much slower.

Comment: I just realized that won;t work for me because I need this to work on items that are have display:block already. In other words, items with display none should not be affected. Thanks.

Comment: You could add the `:visible` selector, to only hide the elements that are visible.